# Adding word objects in to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

class Ordliste {

  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void lesBok(String filnavn) throws Exception {
    File fil = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(fil);

    while(s.hasNextLine()){
        leggTilOrd(s.nextLine());
    }
  }

  private void leggTilOrd(String ord){

    Ord w = new Ord(ord);
      if (list.contains(w)) {
          w.oekAntall();
      }
      else {
          list.add(w);
      }
    }

  }

    class Ord {

      private String tekst;
      private int verdi = hentAntall();

      public Ord(String tekst){
        this.tekst = tekst;
        this.verdi = verdi;
      } //Konstruktoer

      public String toString(){
        return tekst;
      }

  public int hentAntall(){
    return verdi;
  }

  public void oekAntall(){
    verdi++;
  }
}
```

What I am basically trying to do, is reading a words from a txt.file. The code is supposed to only save each word once, and add "verdi" 1 up each time it repeats.

What have I done wrong? "ordliste" and "ord" are two different java files. I hope you understand what I've been trying to do, even tho it's in Norwegian.

Comment: how do you start execution? What's in your main()?

Comment: public class test{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

    Ordliste liste = new Ordliste();
    liste.lesBok("scarlet.text");

  }
}

Comment: cant compile the code i have right now.

Comment: why not use String.split? Do you expect each word to be separated by a space,ie, ' '?

Comment: I forgot to say that the textfile replaced every space with linebreaks, there is just one word each line. I think my "leggTilOrd" method does not work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

the code "list.contains(w)"  in method leggTilOrd is not appropriate;

you are not charging the repeat word but the repeat Ord  object.

so if you want to charge the repeat word, your object Ord should overwrite the equals method:

```
class Ord{

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Ord o = (Ord)obj;
    return tekst.equals(o.tekst);
}

private String tekst;
private int verdi = hentAntall();

public Ord(String tekst) {
    this.tekst = tekst;
    this.verdi = verdi;
} // Konstruktoer

public String toString() {
    return tekst;
}

public int hentAntall() {
    return verdi;
}

public void oekAntall() {
    verdi++;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this inside the leggTilOrd method? Because I am not really supposed to change the Ord class.

Comment: I am sorry, i just didn't see the code clearly, your `list` is declared  `ArrayList<String>` not  `ArrayList<Ord>`.   So if you just want to save  non-repeated words in  `list`：use  `list.contains(ord) ` not `list.contains(w) `  in leggTilOrd method is ok.     But i am confused that how do you handler the Ord objects?